# NSURLConnection problems

Tags: objective-c

Hello my problem is that the delegates methods of my NSURLConnection are not being called, I read other post with the same problem but I can't fix this.

```
@implementation firstViewController
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [sendData sendValues];
});
end

other class
@interface SendInformation //this class extend NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
-(void)sendValues{
.......
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] init];
(void)[conn initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
end
```

The connection is working (I have all the delegate methods inside SendInformation.m) the problem is I never get a response, I read that you need to run the connection in the main thread, but if I do that, the  interface will be freeze until the connection is done also I want the NSURLConnection in a different class.

Comment: okay, have you written the delegate methods in your .m?

Comment: yes, I have all the delegates methods inside sendInformation. If i run this in the firstViewcontroller  everything works but I want to run this in a different class, also using dispatch_async so the interface doesn't freeze

Comment: What do you _think_ `initWithRequest:delegate:` does? It looks like you may have gotten it wrong and should look at the documentation again…

Comment: Returns an initialized URL connection and begins to load the data for the URL request.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for creating the connection is strange. You want:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And of course `self` must implement all of the appropriate `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods.

Comment: Thanks but this does not solve the problem, Im running the NSURLConnection inside the dispatch_async so I think the main thread is already terminated when the delegate methods are called.

Comment: The `NSURLConnection` is already asynchronous. There is no need to start it on a background thread.

Comment: Thats true, the reason I put the NSURLConnection in the background thread is because to set the request I have some process that takes a little bit of time, so I think I will need to do that process in background and the connection in the main thread. Thanks

Comment: Here is the solution http://cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/